# how to retrieve imagepath value with count() who has max upvote value

Tags: mysql, sql

My table schema is like this:

```
id   ||   imagepath || upvote || downvote

1    ||   abc.jpg   || 50      ||  5
2    ||   abcd.jpg  || 70      ||  1
3    ||   adc.jpg   || 40      ||  4
4    ||   aec.jpg   || 70      ||  4
5    ||   afc.jpg   || 40      ||  4
```

How can I retrieve the **imagepath** of all records with max upvote and their **count()**.

In the above case, I want to retrieve the **abcd.jpg** & **aec.jpg** with count say **2 records** (how many records matched), because they both have the maximum value of `upvote`, (in this case **70**).

I currently retrieve max upvote **imagepath** by the following query..

```
SELECT imagepath FROM uploadimage ORDER BY upvote DESC LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible by using join or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select imagepath from uploadimage
where upvote in (
   select max(upvote) from uploadimage
)
```

This will actually return two records each containing the imagepath. How can you expect to have a count returned too? I doesn't make sense as the count is the amount of records.

Comment: thanks it's working fine but i don't want to fire two queries.. is it possible using join?

Comment: is it possible by one query? bcz two query will take time to run and it may decrease performance.. when i have lacs of record in my table

Comment: It is one query with a subquery. I don't think you can do that without a subquery. There shouldn't be any performance issues, though. You could also have a descending index in upvote and that should return pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from uploadimage
where upvote = (select max(upvote) from  uploadimage)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96a292/1)